# VB.NET TCP Server Receiving Data Properly

Tags: vb.net, tcp, server

I have a multithread(with Backgroundworker) TCP Server which is developed by VB.NET. It works very good when client and server at same machine. But when i connect to server from another computer which is at same LAN it works different. At this case it works good until i start to send messages consecutively (3-4 messages at a second). I send :
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi

and server gets this messages such :

Hi
HiHi
HiHiHi
Hi 
etc.

It's very interesting that this issue occurs only when client is at other computer at LAN.

Here is my listen Sub :

```
Sub listen_port6(ByVal b As BackgroundWorker)
    Dim server As TcpListener
    server = Nothing
    Try

        Dim port As Int32 = 8085

        server = New TcpListener(IP, port)

        server.Start()

        Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
        Dim data As String = Nothing

        While True
            Dim client As Sockets.TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient()
            Dim ipend As Net.IPEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint
            PublicIP = ""
            If Not ipend Is Nothing Then
                PublicIP = ipend.Address.ToString
            End If
            b.ReportProgress(1)
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

            Dim i As Int32
            Dim k As Short
            For k = 0 To 1024
                bytes(k) = 0
            Next
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

            While (i <> 0)
                data = ""
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                Debug.Print(data)
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            End While
            client.Close()
        End While
    Catch errore As Exception
        Error_Print(errore.Message)
    Finally
        server.Stop()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: BeginReceive method can solve my problem?

Comment: I found answer myself. Here is a great article about my problem. I hope it will be useful who has such problem :

[http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html)